# How to stop ADF from formatting negative numeric string values in SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, csv, azure-data-factory

I am new to ADF.

I have a copy data activity that uploads data from a csv file into a SQL Server table. The mapping for every column in the activity is string -> nvarchar. In the csv I have columns that contain values such as -100. Yet the copy data activity converts this string value into (100) in my SQL table. How do I stop this conversion?

The real goal would be to have ADF upload the string csv column into a money SQL table column. However on csv side the values in the string column are formatted as -, -100, 100 and the - (representing 0) can not be easily converted to money by ADF, or at least I am not aware of a way to do it?

EDIT: Ok so the columns are formatted as Number in the excel csv, so despite displaying -100 ADF is reading (100)? Is there an activity I can use to replace these parentheses with negative?

Comment: ADF won't convert anything that way. We can't guess what you're doing, or how you display the values. `(10)` is a format used in financial reports. No programming tool would convert to to that format, or display data that way. Are you loading the data in Excel perhaps? As for the money type, better avoid it. It offers no benefits over `numeric(p,s)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The data source is an excel csv, the column I just learned is formatted as Number, so what I see as -100 ADF sees as (100)? Is there an activity to deal with this so that ADF also reads -100?

Comment: CSV files aren't Excel files, they're plain old text files with Values Separated by Commas. They have no formatting or even types. When you double-click a `.csv` file, Excel *imports* it using the current user's defaults. Any kind of styling and formatting, eg showing negative numbers in parentheses, is done by Excel

Comment: On the other hand, Excel files (xlsx) are ZIP packages containing XML files. They have types like numbers and dates. Numbers and dates aren't stored as strings. Did someone open a CSV in Excel, save it after formatting as `xlsx` and then you tried to import it, treating the numeric columns as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the negative number (-100) represented in between parenthesis in Excel, and save the file as comma separated values, the would be as shown below:

```
id,name
(100.00),Ana
2.00 ,Topson
100.00 ,Ceb
20.00 ,Miracle
```

- To change it back to -100, you can do the following steps. First use the lookup activity on this data. The following is how the data would look:

[image]

- Now, using the set variable activity to replace the `(` with `-` and `)` with an empty space. The following is the dynamic content that I used:

```
@replace(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'(','-'),')','')
```

[image]

- Now using OPENJSON, you can insert the data from this array of objects string directly into your table. The following is the query that I used:

```
INSERT INTO t1
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON('@{variables('tp')}')
WITH (id NVARCHAR(100),name NVARCHAR(100))
```

[image]

- The following is how the data reflects in the SQL server table. I have used azure SQL database for demonstration:

[image]

Comment: I ended up doing exactly this but on SQL side of things, thanks for explaining how it can be done in ADF